# Democratic queue in Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, redis, sidekiq

Users can create a `Project` object that contain multiple tasks. When user tells the project to `execute` all those tasks are put on the default queue from Sidekiq.

The problem is: if a user creates a project with 1000 tasks and hit the `execute` buttom, all those 1000 tasks are put in queue. If just after that, another user creates a project with only one task, when he hits executes this project, its only task is put on the end of the line.

I'd like that background process to work on a more democratic way. If each project has its own queue, chances are that the one task from the second project is executed before the end of the 1000 tasks queue.

To do so, I will need separe queues for each project, and it should be dynamically created. I'm trying to accomplish that using the following instead of `perform_async`:

```
Sidekiq::Client.push('queue' => "project_#{self.project.id}", 'class' => TaskWorker, 'args' => [self.id])
```

However, when I try to `execute` a project, all the tasks are placed in a queue called "project_somenumber" but none of them is executed. It seems that when I use `Sidekiq::Client.push`, I need to tell the queue to start executing. Is it correct? How can I *start* that queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sidekiq doesn't support dynamic queue names.  When you start Sidekiq, you tell it which queues to process with "sidekiq -q queue1 -q queue2 ..."  Please see Sidekiq's Advanced Options wiki page for more detail.

Comment: Has this changed at all?  We've been using sidekiq for one of our apps  but the specs are now calling for dynamically generated queues (one for each device we have).  It would be ridiculous to have to restart the app every time we added a device just to pickup the new queue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and solved it by creating helper method like this:

```
def sidekiq_queue(name)
  [name.to_s, Settings.sidekiq_ns].join('_')
end

...

class MyWorker
  sidekiq_options quque: sidekiq_queue(:sync)
end
```

I use dynamic settings.yml file where set sidekiq namespace.

PS: And of cause you should set this dymanic queue in sidekiq.yml.