# Sidekiq - Keep one client from using all workers

Tags: sidekiq

We have an app that has many different clients. We allow clients to do long-running tasks such as importing large CSV files. Currently, we keep things fair by only allowing 1 import per client at a time and running the entire import in a single job.

We would like to split large jobs into many smaller jobs, like a 10,000-line CSV import into 10,000 1-line imports. The problem with this is is that a single long job could use all processing power, postponing another client's short job that normally would have run concurrently and finished quickly.

We have thousands of clients and they are added daily/weekly.

Is there some way to fairly share workers between clients without hacking the settings file with thousands of queues? ([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530865/democratic-queue-in-sidekiq) is similar, but doesn't really get a good answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Put the import jobs into a low priority queue.  Put the short jobs into the default queue so the short jobs are always picked up before the low priority stuff.

Comment: Yep. We already do that. However, one client's import might take 1 hour and another client's might take 1 second. That's the scenario I'm thinking of.  We could set priority by job size, but that could lead to madness. I would just like a clean way to allocate resources fairly by account. I thought maybe Enterprise Rate Limiting concurrency could help, but I don't think it will.

Comment: Well as you noted, if the imports are split up into lots of little jobs, that won't matter.

Comment: To a certain extent, yes that's true. In my example above, if I have 25 threads and the 1 hour job scales perfectly such that it runs in 2.4 minutes, that still means that someone with a few second job will have to wait 2.4 minutes for it to complete if they start it right after, right?

Comment: No.  Sidekiq will check for a higher priority job after **every** small import job.